# Passing a matrix of strings to a function that modifies it

Tags: c, arrays, string, matrix

I'm trying to allocate a matrix of strings in the main, and let other functions access and modify it, with the modifications being visible to all other functions.

This is how i'm allocating the matrix:

```
int i = 0;
char*** jobs = calloc(30, sizeof(char **));
for(int z = 0; z < 30; z++) {
    jobs[z] = calloc(30, sizeof(char*));
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        jobs[z][i] = calloc(30, sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

This is how i'm passing the matrix to function ***loop***:

```
loop(&i, &jobs);
```

*i also need 'i' to be modified and accessed by them all, but it seems to work, so don't worry about it.

This is my definition of function ***loop***:

```
void loop(int *i, char**** jobs)
```

Which also calls another function, ***execute***, and passes the matrix to it. 
***execute*** should be able to make modifications to the matrix that are visible by other functions.

I'm trying to access one of the elements in the matrix "jobs" like this inside "execute":

```
 *jobs[*i][0] = "hello";
 *i += 1;
```

*Notice how I also used the "i" I passed by reference.

Edit:
My question: Am I passing the matrix as I should? 
For example, I need to access elements I added in ***exec*** in another function called ***jobs*** which prints these elements, but it prints "" (nothing) instead.

Here's ***jobs***:

```
int sh_jobs(char**** jobs){
int i = 0;
while(jobs[i][0] != NULL) {
    printf("[%d]   %s   %s   %s\n", i, *jobs[i][0], *jobs[i][1]);
    i++;
}
return 1;
```

}

It DOES go into the while loop, which means the value isn't NULL, but it doesn't print the element.

***jobs*** call inside ***execute***:

```
sh_jobs(jobs);
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @ScottHunter 
my changes are only kept local and not seen by other functions. I'll edit it and add my question.

Comment: It would be way-way-way easier for you and other if you would `struct string_s { char *str; }; struct strings_s { struct string_s *strings; }; struct pragraph_s { struct strings_s *paragraphs; }; struct book_s { struct paragraph_s *paragraphs; }`. Then passing a pointer to book is just `loop(... struct book_s *book)` with easy access `book->paragraphs[1].strings[5]` - is a 5 string in first paragraph in a book.

Comment: If the jobs are supposed to be visible to every other function and you want to create an array of jobs, just make the array of jobs global.

Comment: @KamilCuk
using structs instead of the matrix of strings? or as a part of an array of strings?
Please put this comment in a separate answer so it becomes more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array index operator `[]` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.  So `*jobs[*i][0]` isn't doing what you think it is.

Also, when you assign a string constant to an element of your matrix, you're overwriting a pointer to the memory you allocated causing a memory leak.

You need to add parenthesis around `*jobs`, and you need to use `strcpy` to copy the string:

```
 strcpy((*jobs)[*i][0], "hello");
```